# Fetching data from relational database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have got 2 tables; table1 and table2. Both of them are related to eachother with a common `groupid` I am able to query the second table successfully using the following code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `memberid`='$id'"); 
$data['relation'] = $query->result_array();
```

Now using `groupid` result I want to query the first table i.e. table1

I have tried the following methods, without any success:

```
for($ii = 0 ; $ii < count($data['relation']) ; $ii++){
        $id = $data['relation'][$ii]['groupid'];
        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE `id`='$id'");
}             

$data1['group'] = $query1->result_array();

$fine = array_merge($data, $data1);
print_r(count($fine)); // the count result is 1 ideally should be 2
```

The above code only returns the last row of the `table1` however I am looking for all the results.

When I run the above code inside the "for" loop, it shows me a count of 33:

```
    for($ii = 0 ; $ii < count($data['relation']) ; $ii++){
        $id = $data['relation'][$ii]['groupid'];
        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE `id`='$id'");

$data1['group'] = $query1->result_array();

$fine = array_merge($data, $data1);
print_r(count($fine)); // the count result is 33 ideally should be 2
}
```

I know how to achieve this in core php however not too sure how to do it in CI. I am new to CI, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Utpal

Comment: generally speaking: if you're running nested loops, and the inner query is using data from the query, then almost always the queries should be re-written as a single `JOIN`ed query. And as you're writing the queries, you're probably vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Consider [using the tools that the framework provides you](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) - or there's really no point in using a framework

Comment: Thanks sjagr and Marc will keep that in mind.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ok = array();
     for($ii = 0 ; $ii < count($data['relation']) ; $ii++){
            $id = $data['relation'][$ii]['groupid'];
            print_r ($id);
            echo "<br>";
            $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE `id`='$id'");
            $data1['group'][$ii]= $query1->result_array();

    }
        //print_r($data1['group']);
        $fine = array_merge($data, $data1);
        print_r($fine);
```

You need to create a array ($data1) outside this for loop and define $query->result_array(); inside forloop as shown above